# How does hashed inverted page table work?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, hash-tables, paging

I understand hash function and inverted page table, but then the book I read describes something called hashed inverted page table (use hash to accelerate the finding because IPT is large), with TLB used. I don't understand why there is an arrow point to itself inside the hash table? Could anyone explain the mechanism?

> [image: my h-IPT]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86845/discussion-on-question-by-ptr-user7813604-how-does-hashed-inverted-page-table-wo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your picture, one definitely see a [hash table collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) solution. If one carefully examine it, will see that the table uses itself to solve the collision, that is [Open Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing).

In open addressing, the collision can be resolved by many methods;

- Linear Probing
- Quadratic Probing
- Double hashing.

It might be Double Hashing or Quadratic Probing but the information is not enough to resolve.